# Can a socket read the TCP window update from the other side?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Is there a socket API to read the TCP window update which is received from the other side of connection, hopefully in Linux socket?

Comment: There is no such API, that I'm aware of. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: When socket send buffer is full, we mark this as "CONGESTION" which can be caused by 2 possibilities. The congestion in the network or the receiver buffer full. And would like to mark these separately.

Comment: I do not know of any way for applications to get that kind of information.

Comment: You might be able to programmatically write a sniffer type program that grabs those TCP packets from the wire and processes that information. I've never used them but I think libpcap and scapy are two such packages that are available depending on your platform/programming language.